# Возникает ошибка в использовании python json и pickle. Python не дает записать файлы в директорию. Подскажите как устранить?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как устранить ошибку? Явно дело в правах, но не могу понять что делать. Заранее благодарю за помощь

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PythonProject/Alexandra/myPack1/123.py", line 9, in <module>
    with open(file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\PythonProject\\Alexandra\\myPack1'
```

```
import json

favourite_tracks = [
    {'name': 'Вечная любовь', 'artist': 'Агата Кристи'},
    {'name': 'Angel', 'artist': 'Attack'},
    {'name': 'Jumming', 'artist': 'Bob Marley'}
]

file_name = r'C:\PythonProject\Alexandra\myPack1'
with open(file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(favourite_tracks, f)

print('done')
```

Answer (score 1):

Из текста ошибки видно, что myPack1 - это директория, в которой лежит ваш скрипт. Вы пытаетесь открыть эту директорию как файл, а вместо этого нужно открывать файл в этой директории, например:

```
file_name = r'C:\PythonProject\Alexandra\myPack1\file.txt'
with open(file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(favourite_tracks, f)
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас, добрый человек :-)